# Packaging a node-webkit application into an exe file

Tags: macos, windows-installer, exe, node-webkit

I'm very new to building a node-webkit application. So I took a job to reverse engineer an already built application and re-bundle it up.

Here are my app files:

http://www.eric-winchester.com/images/ss1.png

I figured out how to repackage the app into app.nw and then into the package files for a Mac so that it runs MyApp.app and even create MyApp.dmg.

http://www.eric-winchester.com/images/ss2.png

So I'm not having any problems making the application on a Mac. However, Now I need to bundle the "app" folder into an exe file so when a CD is entered into the users PC an AUTORUN file (which I'm not having a problem with) will open up an installer exe and install the application.

I've tried a bunch of different compiler programs but I cannot get the files and folders into an executable file. 
Am I way off here in what I'm trying to do? And if so, can someone direct me to a place that will show me how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

First, copy app.nw file into folder where nw.exe exists. 
Then you can try following command in cmd:

> path_to_folder_which_contains_nw.exe>copy nw.exe+app.nw app.exe

You will get the message "1 file copied" after successful app.exe created.
It will create a single executable file but it will not run outside that folder.
Then you can use windows installer like iexplore.exe(defualt windows installer) to create installer exe.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the instruction on [How to package and distribute your apps](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps), it described quite well how to [path the exe](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps#windows-1) and [which files should be shipped](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps#which-files-should-be-shipped) with the exe.

My recommendation is that you won't do it manually. Instead use [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to build the exe file. To get started, use [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) and [generator-node-webkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-node-webkit) for a basic project layout and build script.

Then, making win executable (or mac) is easy as:

```
grunt dist-mac
grunt dist-win
```